# Manually running dart server in Google App Engine VM

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, google-cloud-platform

How do you manually run a server side dart application from within a google app engine VM?

I see that you can SSH into the box, but I don't see any of the source code.  Is it all contained in a separate docker file?  I'm trying to debug an issue with the code, but I can't seem to find any of the code in that vm.

Comment: I believe you can't ssh to appengine (unless you have user managed VM on flex).

Comment: For what reason do you need to SSH into a particular instance?  Knowing your use case may help with providing an effective alternative as SSH into a user-managed flex instance is not recommended.

Comment: I have a server side dart app that works fine in test, but when I move to the app engine for whatever reason it doesn't work.  I can't seem to get enough information from the stdout.  I was wondering if I could view / modify the dart script to quickly debug without having to re-build the complete docker file.

Comment: Because dart leverages a custom runtime, it's on flex.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option here would be to use the Dart VM observatory for debugging. It is listening on port 8181. In the base Dockerfile [google/dart-runtime-base](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/dart-runtime-base/) port 8181 is forwarded.

To be able to access the observatory you also need to open that port on App Engine as well. This is handled through `app.yaml` as described in the App Engine [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml). This is also described in the [README.md](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_docker/tree/master/runtime-base#using-this-image-with-app-engine-managed-vms) for the base Dockerfile `google/dart-runtime-base`.

Comment: This is how to debug an app running in the google cloud.  My question is about manually running the app which would allow for quick modification / debug cycles.